# how i could retrieve data from mysql using php code

Tags: php

I'm still a beginner in the PHP
so I need your help ... I have a small database Containing

- id & content &  links

I want to retrieve the content data using the id .
so I need the php code which could help me

Comment: Plz send me teh codez ? There are *plenty* tutorials out there on how to do this. Try doing a few, and if you run into an actual problem,  people here will be happy to help you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php happy reading.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpass");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$id = 5;
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = {$id}");
$r = mysql_fetch_object($q);

echo $r->links;

?>
```

Supposing you need to get only one row from table.

Answer (score 0):

if your database is mySQL

read http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_connect.asp

and

http://www.novaksblog.com/2007/10/02/database-connection-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

Object oriented approaches:

PDO:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
- PDO tutorial: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#1

ADOdb:

- http://adodb.sourceforge.net/